# EKS pods multi tenant with RDS

Tags: kubernetes, rds, amazon-eks

I have an EKS cluster with ASG.
I want to restrict pods that are in the specific name space to connect to specific RDS services.

Is this available in AWS, is there any suggestions how to do so?

Looking for best practices that are already running in production.

Comment: Might want to use kube2iam or equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t believe there is a way to whitelist just a single namespace in order to access your RDS instance. This is mainly because clusters are shared and AWS services don’t really understand what kubernetes namespace is.

In order to achieve connectivity you can have a private vpc peering or a publicly available RDS on which you are going to whitelist elastic IP attached to VPC NAT gateway. I would strongly advise you use private vpc peering and then you at least know that connections are private.

Finally, RDS access is going to be allowed for entire cluster as you can’t really limit it to a single set of resources. However, because your RDS requires user credentials to access any data inside I don’t believe that it is such a big issue to have your cluster whitelisted against RDS.

Comment: If i'm running in multi tenant environment, and I enable all the cluster to access a specific RDS it's expose all pods which mean all tenants to all RDS. Wondered if there is a way to do similar solution with calcio ?

Comment: With calico you will be able to limit access to certain ports from within different namespaces but it will not work very well if you have many of them. At some point you will find yourself in a situation where you have too many namespaces and all of them need access to a particular port which will be MySQL or Postgres default port.

Comment: Note that I have exactly the same scenario and with kubernetes clusters it is always the same issue. My best advise is to use private connectivity and ensure that credentials are not easy to guess.

Comment: That's right, although I really was hoping to find something similar to:
https://github.com/jtblin/kube2iam , that has been running and certified in production

Comment: @MickeyHovel just to let you know please start moving away from kube2iam and start using kiam which has been developed by uSwitch. Much better implementation and solution.

Comment: can you please explain, why? as I found in the page it is based on what I sent ..

Comment: The Kiam suggestion is slightly off topic. But please consider reading https://www.google.co.uk/amp/s/www.bluematador.com/blog/iam-access-in-kubernetes-kube2iam-vs-kiam%3fhs_amp=true

Answer (score 0):

You can use Pod Security Groups to achieve this.

- [Blog Post explaining Pod Security Groups](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/introducing-security-groups-for-pods/)
- [Tutorial for setting up Pod Security Groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/security-groups-for-pods.html)

If you want all Pods of a namespace to be part of a EC2 Security Group, you should be able to use an empty `podSelector` in your `SecurityGroupPolicy`.

```
apiVersion: vpcresources.k8s.aws/v1beta1
kind: SecurityGroupPolicy
metadata:
  name: my-security-group-policy
  namespace: my-namespace
spec:
  securityGroups:
    groupIds:
      - my_pod_security_group_id
  podSelector:
```